# Meteor cannot get data

Tags: mongodb, iron-router

Im new to meteor, I have a problem I can't get collection from mongodb (i use iron router )

/client/routes.js

```
Router.route('/page', function(){
  this.render('page');
});
```

/client/foo.js

```
city = new Mongo.Collection('data');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.foo.helpers({
    data: function(){
      return city.find();
    }
  });

}
```

client/views/foo.html

```
<template name="foo">
    {{#each data}}
        {{> all_data}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
<template name="all_data">
    <li>{{city}}</li>
</template>
```

in chrome console the command city.find() give me:

> L…n.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, _selectorId:
>   undefined, matcher: M…o.Matcher, skip: undefined…}

and in mongo console db.data.find() it work fine

i think there a problem to connect to mongodb

Comment: try a `console.table (city.find().fetch());` in your client code or console. The `find()` method returns a cursor, the `findOne()` or find().fetch() returns an array of documents.

Comment: `city.find().fetch()` return just `[]` , and `findOne()` return undefined

Comment: If you removed the autopublish package, keep in mind that you need to define `allow-deny` rules and publications in order to access your data on the client side. See https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/. You also need to define your collection in a `both` folder, so it refers to the same collection both on server and client (not sure this is mandatory if names matches).

Answer (score 0):

The collections need to be defined on both server and client side for autopublish to work -- files in /client are only executed on the client side, so `city = new Mongo.Collection('data');` is unknown to the server.

Move the file

```
 /client/foo.js
```

into the parent directory

```
 /foo.js
```

And it will likely work

Comment: Just tested it, and apart from that your template is called "foo" and the router is rendering "page", then it worked perfectly well for me.   Change the name of the page you render to be the same as the template name, and put all the files in the top level directory before you start playing around with /client and /server

Comment: Also, you do not say that you have removed any of the packages, such as `insecure` or `autopublish` -- if you have your solutin would look differently.   Ty to create a new project, just add `meteor add iron:router` and move the files to the top level directory of new project, and it should all work for you.